# Extract tar.gz file in perl

Tags: xml, extract, tar

I have a tar.gz file which is of appx 60 MB in size ... I need to extract the XML file insided that tar.gz file .. but I'm getting Out Of Memory error while using the below command..

```
use Archive::Extract;
$TAR_FILE_WORK_PATH='C:\..\..\..\Perl\IN\test_sample.xml.tar.gz';
$WORK_DIR = 'C:\..\..\..\Perl\IN\Work';
my $extract_obj = Archive::Extract->new(archive => $TAR_FILE_WORK_PATH, type => 'tgz');
if (!($extract_obj->extract(to => $WORK_DIR))){
print "Error extracting tar file\n";
}
else {
print "Extracted tar file $LATEST_FILE_NAME successfully";
}
```

Please help me in extracting the tar.gz file to a different directory in a efficient way....

Comment: I tried using Archive::Tar as well ..below is the code ..    use Archive::Tar;
    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;

    $tar->read('C:/Srinivas/../../../Perl/IN/Work/test_sample.xml.tar.gz');
    $tar->extract();                                                     Still I'm getting Out Of memory error .... Appreciate some response ...

Answer (score 0):

Ih the answers of the next questions:

[Out Of Memory while extracting tar.gz file using perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411960/out-of-memory-while-extracting-tar-gz-file-using-perl)

They mention using PREFER_BIN maybe helps.