# Out Of Memory while extracting tar.gz file using perl

Tags: xml, tags, extract, archive

I have a tar.gz file which is of around 60 MB and that file has a XML file inside it ...and while extracting the file I'm getting **Out Of Memory!** error ...
Below is the code I'm using for extracting the file ....

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Extract;
$TAR_FILE_PATH = 'C:/Perl/IN/test_sample.tar.gz';
$WPARK_DIR = 'C:/Srinivas/Perl/WORK';
my $extract_obj = Archive::Extract->new(archive => $TAR_FILE_PATH, type => 'tgz');
$extract_obj->extract(to => $WORK_DIR);
```

Its failing at the last line while extracting the tar.gz file into WORK_DIR. Can someone suggest a best way to handle this and extract the huge XML file inside the tar.gz file..

Comment: the XML file inside the tar.gz file is around 800 MB ....

Comment: can someone help me in getting out of this error !!!

Answer (score 1):

The Archive::Extract module can use either a pure perl solution or fall back to a system call. You can set the PREFER_BIN to force it to use the system call which is less memory intensive.

http://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Extract.html#Supporting-Very-Large-Files